# I need to figure out how much paint is needed to cover an area, I'm having problems with it. Help me or give me an idea

Tags: php, calculator

```
$width = 10; //width
$length = 10; //Length
$door = 2; // Door area
$square = $width * $length - $door; //Total area to be painted
$perMeter = 1;  //Where $w is the amount of paint to paint 1m2
$total = $square * $perMeter; //The total amount of paint is sufficient for painting.
$containers = array(5,12,18,4,8,1); //The values for the number of containers are in liters.
```

How many barrels will be needed 5,12,18,4,8,1 (will gradually get from the largest part to the smallest part)

Comment: At least you have to know the formula.

Comment: Modulo the target volume by the largest container, then proceed with the volume remainder and smaller containers, until only 1s can be subtracted. (Doesn't even need a knapsack algorithm.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The whole file can look like that

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

$width = 10; //width
$length = 10; //Length
$door = 2; // Door area
$square = $width * $length - $door; //Total area to be painted
$perMeter = 1;  //Where $w is the amount of paint to paint 1m2
$total = $square * $perMeter; //The total amount of paint is sufficient for painting.

echo 'Total barrels needed: ' . $total . "barrels\n";

$containers = array(5,12,18,4,8,1); //The values for the number of containers are in liters.

rsort($containers);

$counter = 0;

while ($counter < count($containers)) {
    $total -= ($amount = intdiv($total, $containers[$counter])) * $containers[$counter];
    echo sprintf("%d barrel container - %d\n", $containers[$counter], $amount);
    $counter++;
}
```

Look at the variable names, meaningful variable names are very important, if you want your code to be supported easily. And of course you can change the value of variables.